# How to give the OnItemClick method the correct context to function properly?

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener

I have this code:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Cursor cursor = databaseHelper.getAgendaToEdit(id);
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), EditAgendaActivity.class);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            intent.putExtra("id", cursor.getString(0));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

and error is:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.zeroe.EditAgendaActivity; no empty constructor
```

The goal is to just start a new activity when clicking an item in the list. I am calling this method from my main activity, which

```
list
```

is from as well. I assume the issue is coming from the fact that I am not getting the context from where my ListView is. Problem is it should be working because I am providing the correct context, at least I am assuming. ANy help would be much appreciated.

If anyone needs me to clarify, please let me know and I will do so right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Activity` subclasses all need a default constructor. Evidently `EditAgendaActivity` does not have one. That's where the problem lies, and not in the code that you posted.

Generally, you should only have a default (no-arg) constructor for an `Activity` subclass or no constructor at all (and let the compiler generate a no-arg constructor for you).

Comment: Hmm, But that does't make sense to me, only because I called another activity with a constructor through an intent. In either case, I thought extending from Activity class always had to have a Bundle constructor, meaning I need a constructor. Any explanations on this?

Comment: Damn, ok, that was a dumb mistake of me. You are correct lol. I mistakingly made my onCreate a constructor. I apologize for that and appreciate the knowledge in understanding that fact. Thank you!